# Why the customized delete() function of the model may not be executed in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

How to understand following statements in Django's official documents?

> Keep in mind that this will, whenever possible, be executed purely in SQL, and so the `delete()` methods of individual object instances will not necessarily be called during the process. If you’ve provided a custom `delete()` method on a model class and want to ensure that it is called, you will need to “manually” delete instances of that model (e.g., by iterating over a QuerySet and calling `delete()` on each object individually) rather than using the bulk `delete()` method of a QuerySet.

In most cases, we still need to call the original `delete()` functions in the superclasses in our customized `delete()` function. Why the customized version of `delete()` function may not be executed due to the underlying SQL? What does it mean by mentioning the bulk operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a model called `MyModel`, there are two different `delete` methods :

- one in `MyModel`, used for each object

  ```
  m = MyModel.objects.first()
  m.delete() # here you use the methode defined in MyModel
  ```
- one for the QuerySet that delete all objects at once with a single SQL :

  ```
  qs = MyModel.objects.filter(...)
  qs.delete() # this is the queryset bulk delete
  ```

  Here the `delete` method of `MyModel`will not be executed.

The doc says that if you want to delete all objects in a queryset and still call your custom `MyModel.delete` method, then you have to do :

```
for q in qs:
    q.delete()
```

Comment: Get it! It's the function with the same signature but belong to two class, MyModel and QuerySet.

Answer (score 0):

Wont work if you call `Foo.objects.all().delete()` (a QuerySet).

Will work if you call

```
for foo in Foo.objects.all():
    foo.delete()
```

(individual objects)